# Error: Target container is not a DOM element (when running Purescript Pux Program)

Tags: purescript, purescript-pux

I've compiled [this program](https://github.com/alexmingoia/purescript-pux/blob/master/examples/counter/Main.purs) with Purescript 0.12.5 but when I look at the index.html in Firefox 67.0.2 I get the following error in the web console:

Error: Target container is not a DOM element. app.js:5160:15

Here is the index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<title>PS3</title>   

<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"
   crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-   
   dom.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>

<script src='app.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're loading the program *before* the `<div id="app">` element, so the element doesn't yet exist at the time the program is running and trying to find it.

Try moving the `<script>` tag after the `<div>`:

```
<html>
<head>
  ...
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script src='app.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```